# Why is it saying that there is a syntax error for the if/else statement I wrote?

Tags: logic, ti-basic

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the sum of a geometric series on a TI-84.

```
Prompt A

Prompt R

Prompt N

If N=100 and abs(R)<1

Disp (A/1-R)

Else

Disp (A(1-R^N))/(1-r)
```

It says that there is a syntax error at the Else line.

Comment: Make sure your colons are in the correct places.

Answer (score 1):

`Else` can only be paired with an `If .. Then` construct, not a plain `If`. So:

```
Prompt A,R,N
If N=100 and abs(R)<1
Then
Disp A/(1-R
Else
Disp (A(1-R^N))/(1-R
```

In general the `If.. Then .. Else .. End` construct should be closed by `End` but in this case the program exits anyway so it makes no difference. There is some documentation of this in the official TI-BASIC manual and you can check out a more detailed version [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/if).